# Al abrir el navegador de pruebas de forma silenciosa con Selenium, no extrae bien la información de la web

Tags: python, web, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

Estoy haciendo un programa empleando técnicas de Web Scraping con Selenium Webdriver para extraer información de varias páginas web. Para ello se crea un driver del navegador escogido, en este caso, Chrome. Cuando abres la web para que analice el contenido html y extraiga la información, se abre un navegador de pruebas simulado. [image: navegador simulado] Me gustaría que no se abriese o no fuese visible para el usuario el navegador de pruebas, sin embargo he probado varias opciones y si no se abre el navegador no extrae la información de la web. Sólo me pasa para una de las webs, para la otra lo hace correctamente.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("headless")  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: intenta haciendo `.add_argument("--headless")`

Comment: Tampoco funciona. El navegador sí se abre en modo silencioso, pero eso ya lo tenía. El problema es que si se abre así, no interactúa bien con la web y no extrae nada

Comment: podrías editar la pregunta y agregar la url a la que quieres consultar, para descartar que no sea un caso de timeout ?